# Microsoft Edge blocking downloads

Tags: download, microsoft-edge

I have a zip file, saved in S3, served by AWS Cloudfront

I have a button on the website, button sends a request to a server, server generates the presigned url and 302 redirects to that presigned url. The presigned url has `response-content-disposition=attachment` to force the download

It works perfectly and has been working perfectly for 10 years on every browser, until last week Edge released a security update => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-downloads-interruptions

Has anyone faced the same issue / found a solution? Any ideas of what we might try?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The update you mentioned refers to the `Microsoft Edge for Business`  in stable version 116? If this is the case, have you correctly configured `ExemptFileTypedownloadWarnings` policy? As far as I know, this strategy is not affected by this update. You can briefly refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmore-personal-browser-policies), which contains the affected strategy list.

Comment: No, the policy is for all the edge instances, not just for Business. Unfortunately

Comment: Because of this, I am confused by your question, I also did not find in the documentation that `ZIP` is defined as a dangerous file type, I tried downloading the example file in the [File Examples](https://file-examples.com/index.php/text-files-and-archives-download/) site and it also executed normally without any danger prompt information. So, by default it will work fine, what is the download prompt you receive, or what error message is there?